# MS App Analytics timeline chart

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have data in the following format. Is it possible to create a time line chart using App Analytics. I am trying to easily identify the calls which overlap in my DataSet.

```
| Start Time           | End Time             | Call Name           | Duration
|----------------------|----------------------|---------------------|----------
| 17:41:30.5001642Z    | 17:41:30.703291Z     | CreateDraftEnvelope | 203
| 17:41:31.0711234Z    | 17:41:31.0867211Z    | CreateLock          | 21
| 17:41:31.1189342Z    | 17:41:31.1345349Z    | addDocument         | 17
| 17:41:31.1961265Z    | 17:41:31.2117613Z    | addDocument         | 17
| 17:41:31.4243498Z    | 17:41:31.4399953Z    | addDocument         | 19
| 17:41:31.5242518Z    | 17:41:31.5398738Z    | addDocument         | 17
```

I am looking for a chart as follows
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Analytics does not today provide this visualization type. Could you please submit it on our [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/category/161991-analytics)?

Comment: Thanks I have posted it in the UserVoice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/19506784-render-gantt-charts